# Terraform AWS - cannot connect to EC2 instance (SSH port is not accessible from outside)

Tags: terraform

I am trying to build myself an small EC2 instance that is being launched into an VPC with EIB and a Subnet / Internet Gateway and Security Groups.

`main.tf`

```
resource "aws_instance" "live" {
  ami = "ami-060e472760062f83f"
  instance_type = "t2.nano"
  key_name = "xxx"

  network_interface {
    device_index = 0
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.multi-ip.id
  }
}

resource null_resource "ansible_web" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_elasticache_cluster.redis,
    aws_internet_gateway.gw,
    aws_instance.live
  ]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false ansible-playbook -u ubuntu --private-key './xxx.pem' -i '${aws_instance.live.public_dns},' ansible/main.yml"
  }
}
```

Security groups in `network.tf`

```
resource "aws_security_group" "all-outbound-traffic" {
  name        = "all-outbound-traffic-group"
  description = "Allow traffic to leave the AWS instance"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.default.id

  tags = {
    Name = "Outbound Traffic Security Group"
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.default.cidr_block]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "ssh-group" {
  name        = "ssh-access-group"
  description = "Allow traffic to port 22 (SSH)"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.default.id

  tags = {
    Name = "SSH Access Security Group"
  }

  ingress {
    description = "SSH to VPC"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.default.cidr_block]
  }
}
```

Networking nodes in `network.tf`

```
resource "aws_vpc" "default" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true

  tags = {
    Name = "tf-default"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.default.id

  tags = {
    Name = "tf-default"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "default" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.default.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "tf-default"
  }
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "multi-ip" {
  subnet_id   = aws_subnet.default.id
  security_groups = [
    aws_security_group.http-group.id,
    aws_security_group.https-group.id,
    aws_security_group.ssh-group.id,
    aws_security_group.all-outbound-traffic.id,
  ]
}

resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_instance.live,
    aws_eip.lb
  ]

  instance_id = aws_instance.live.id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.lb.id
  network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.multi-ip.id
}

resource "aws_eip" "lb" {
  vpc = true
  network_interface         = aws_network_interface.multi-ip.id
  //associate_with_private_ip = aws_instance.live.private_ip
  depends_on                = [aws_internet_gateway.gw]
}
```

terraform is able to build an setup everything mostly correctly and also in my AWS console it seemingly is all connected correct.

EC2 -> VPC -> Subnet -> Network Interface with Security Groups

From my understanding I should have launched a VPC with a private subnet that is bound to a static IP address provided by EIB module. However, if I try to ssh into the machine, it times out, which leads me into believing I setup the SGs wrong. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the resources outside of terraform (cli/GUI)?

Comment: @Meow_ly what do you mean exactly? I checked the AWS console and to me it all seems correctly setup but obviously it isn't - since I nor terraform can access the EC2 instance.

Comment: Does your subnet have a route for 0.0.0.0/0 pointing to your internet gateway?